# Google Sheets, IF THEN function in adding up closed deals

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that has options for closing customers.

If the cell says "Approved" then the Estimated Quote should appear in the "Closed Deal" column. If it shows "Denied" it shows a "0" dollar value. Pending will also show a "0" value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This site is more of what you are looking for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If A1 is `the cell` and ColumnB the `Closed Deal` column:

```
=if(A1="Approved","the Estimated Quote",if(or(A1="Denied",A1="Pending"),"$0","?"))
```

This can be copied down to act the same on A2 etc. `"the Estimated Quote"` should perhaps be a cell reference.